# Javascript 'Read More' within a Repeater Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Looking for some assistance with a 'Read More' link within a Repeater. I'm having some trouble working out the correct 'jQuery' placement for this and what other configuration of the various elements I need before this will work properly. I'm fairly sure it's tripping up somehow on the ID's of the elements within the repeater but do not have the knowledge yet to diagnose and fix myself. I'll run you through the basic setup of my page.

There is a fairly simple Repeater that loads a paragraph of text, and by default I have set this to only show the first 2 lines of text, with a 'read more' button to view the rest.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterExerts" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="my_text" class="ellipsis">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ExertDescription") %>
        </div>
        <div id="read_more" class="pull-right">more</div>

        <script>
            var style = $('<style>.ellipsis { height: ' + ((parseInt($('.ellipsis').css('line-height')) * 2) + 'px') + ' }</style>');
            $('html > head').append(style);
            $('#read_more').click(function () { 
                $('#my_text').toggleClass('ellipsis');  
            });
        </script>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**What will happen if I click 'more'?** 
The expansion of the div tag works for only the first item in the repeater. This leads me to believe it has something with the way the page is assigning div ID's and that all subsequent Repeaters do not work because of this. If this is the case then how would I go about enabling each of the 'read' expansions to operate just within it's own element?

The other part of the equation to make this work (well, sort of!) is the css. It's as follows.

```
#my_text.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#my_text {
    width: 95%;
}

#read_more {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The repeater is repeating your items with same Id you should work with something that can be repeatable like class.You can set your toggle event on 'ellipsis' class and 'pull-right' directly.